# Persistently changing app config settings programmatically in Laravel.

Tags: php, laravel

In an application I am building, I want to include a few custom artisan commands for updating application config settings like the app name, and database connections. This is mostly because some people that will need to be able to modify these settings are not familiar with Laravel (some of them are still college students). So, I want them to be able to easily modify these settings by simply calling an artisan command.

A problem I am currently running into is that updating config settings using the config() function is not persistent. So, I did a quick search on the internet for a solution. I found [this](https://github.com/AlexanderPoellmann/Laravel-Settings) solution on a similar question here on Stack Overflow. However, when importing the library, composer notifies me that the project has been abandoned and it would be best to find a different solution.

So, is there another solution to help with this task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This solution does not use artisan file but uses command line interface.*

If python is available in your environment, you can move the settings to be modified to your .env file and than install "python-dotenv[cli]" package to modify them without changing your source code.

You can install the package via pip:

```
pip install -U "python-dotenv[cli]"
```

Replace the configuration file to read the configuration from the environment.

```
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
```

then in the folder which laravel is installed; run e.g.:

```
dotenv MAIL_PASSWORD 123456
```

Comment: Hmm... Considering I cannot find a good alternative using Artisan, this may have to work. Thanks. If anyone finds an artisan solution, do let me know though :)

Comment: If using the artisan is important, one way around may be creating an artisan command to run the dotenv command and using php exec function. Eg.: php artisan env:change MAIL_PASSWORD 123456 which will than send the args to dotenv cli command via php exec.